# Argument to find data in large Excel document to later use with other data found

Tags: excel

I have a very large Excel document with something like 7500 rows. Not all of the data is needed, but I want to use some of the data to find how long an order takes from start to end (lead time).

I tried starting with the INDEX function to find and out put individual order numbers based on another cells data ("Order has Shipped"). This formula worked, however it only returns the very first Order Number and no others.

My thought here was that I could do one column that pulled all the order numbers based on the "Order has Shipped" requirement. After that, I would do a similar function to give a second column next to the order numbers that showed the correct data and time stamps. After that, I would do two more columns with basically the same information, but to show when the order was first entered and spit out another time stamp. From these two time stamps, I could do a simple function to calculate the difference in time.

I wanted to put these into new columns so I could also find the average lead time, number of orders shipped, and other things.

=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(L11,G:G,0))

Any help would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: I also tried using MATCH, by doing =MATCH("Order has Shipped*",G:G,0). This returned the the first row number that has a matching "Order has Shipped".

Doing this I got and output of 2309, from there I changed it into an address A2309 using the ADDRESS function.

From there I am thinking I can return the time stamp that is in A2309, but can't figure that part out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using =IF(L1="Order has Shipped",D1,"") to get the Order Numbers and then you can "Find & Select" and click "Go to Special", then click blanks. This will select all the blank values. Then click delete and it will get rid of all the spaces in the rows so you have all the unique order numbers that have been shipped listed in one column.

Comment: You can just adjust the formula to get the additional information is adjacent columns

Comment: That does give me the Order Numbers, but can't be reasonably done for the whole document because of its size.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you don't want to drag it all the way down you can use Crlt+Shift+Down arrow to highlight the whole row and then use Crlt+D to copy the formula down

Comment: I would like for the order numbers to be returned in a cell closer to the top. For example, in cell L2,L3,L4, etc. Or possible on another sheet at cell A2.

Comment: highlight the column, use the "Find & Select" and click "Go to Special", then click blanks. This will select all the blank values. Then click the delete cells button it will bring all the values to the top.

Comment: let me know if this helped. If not I can think of other ways to complete the task.

Comment: I think I found a solution using this =IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Order has Shipped",G:G,0)+Q2,7))="Order has Shipped",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Shipping Station*",H:H,0)+Q2,4)),"")

Q2 starts at zero and increments by one (0,1,2,3). This adds the next order number that is found after the first one with the correct conditions. I can use this to get the information I want.

However, my next question is how to modify this to use in another blank sheet. The sheet I am using now is call Transaction Log. The second sheet I try to put this formula into defaults to Sheet1 when I create it.

Comment: Is the formula exactly the same in the second sheet? Are you just copying and pasting the formula?

Comment: No, I edited to include the 'Transaction Log"! before both G:G and H:H. I also tried doing it as Sheet 1!.

Comment: Try taking the " out so just have Transaction Log! before G:G and H:H